# how to scan text from barcode scanner and add to text box c#

Tags: c#, barcode, barcode-scanner

I am creating a bar-code scanning app in c# that read bar-code value from scanner and then add value to a text box. I don't want to scan value from image.
I tried searching at google but didn't find and suitable answers.

Please tell me how can i scan text or numbers from bar-code and then add them to text-box in c#. i have a plug n play bar code scanner, that scans bar-code without any plugin or driver. bar-code scanner manufacturer and model is symbol LS 2208 USB bar code scanner.
Please help me how can i do this

Sajid

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/296533/Using-a-bar-code-scanner-in-NET

Comment: The scanner will trigger keyboard events, which you can simply catch in the TextBox's keydown etc events. It'll be complete when a return or newline comes along; you need to collect the characters until then.. Make sure the TextBox has Focus!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Reading numbers from hand scanner or bar code reader in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15109959/reading-numbers-from-hand-scanner-or-bar-code-reader-in-c-sharp)